# PC getting stuck at the Intel boot screen

Tags: boot, reboot

there is this strange problem I am facing for quite a while now at the time of starting up my pc.

`WHERE it occurs:` The problem occurs at the very first screen that appears after pressing power button where there are two ‘Intel’ logos with few two digit alphabets which keep on changing at the right bottom of the screen like: `BA` `BC` `EB` usually this screen last for 2, 3 seconds.

`WHEN it occurs:` BUT at the times when the problem occurs my PC remain stuck at this screen at the `BA` point *(see image attached)*, with no CPU activity happening it just remain stagnant there.

`Other Important Observations/Information:`

- This problem ALWAYS occurs when I Restart my PC or even when I
  Shutdown and start it again without switching off main power (UPS +
  Main switch)
- I have also noticed when I have a bootable USB attached to PC at the time of booting up it gets stuck at the `BC` point instead of `BA`
- To correct it I have power it off, switch off electric supply behind
  including UPS, Main power, wait for 3,4 seconds and power it on
  again, than it all works fine.
- I have changed my power supply for the PC as thinking that this issues is somehow related to power problem but didn’t helped, I have also reinstalled windows after this problem but this problem is still there.
- PC configuration: 64 bit system | Intel Core 2 Quad Q8200 | 4 GB Ram |
- Screen shot of screen where PC gets stuck

[image: Screen shot of screen where PC gets stuck]

Kindly help me out with how to get rid of this problem as it gets really problematic in many ways including while installing windows or when you have to restart your pc etc.

Thankyou!

Comment: Try cleaning the insides of the CPU. Or maybe the motherboard is acting funny. How old is the system? And what is the config?

Comment: PC is clean from inside, I keep blowing air in it in a month of two, system is round ~ 3 yrs. old and CPU configurations I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Sorry for not seeing the config. This beats me really. I would say motherboard

Comment: Can you please remove the UPS completely and see if the problem persists. Also, try just 1 stick of RAM. When testing this, remove all devices which are not essential (so, no external USB drives etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These POST codes stads for:

`BA` - Detecting presence of a removable media (IDE, CD-ROM detection, etc.)
`BC` - Enabling/configuring a removable media

If you don't need boot from USB devices. I would try to enable "USB Optimization" at UEFI configuration.

1. At that Intel start screen after power on press `F2`
2. Then in UEFI configuration go to `Boot` tab
3. Enable `USB Optimization`
4. Press `F10` and accept with `Y`

Which usb devices are connected to your computer?

Comment: I wonder if the UPS is connected via USB!

Comment: I think UPS wouln't be detected as removable device. I would bet on keyboard or mouse.

Comment: @Dave Rook: No UPS isnot connected through USB. Its just directly going into the power supply.

Comment: @week Thankyou for explaning codes but I cant locate the option of `USB Optimization` in my boot menu inside intel setup tab, there is `USB boot` but no `USB Optimization`. can you giude me a lil more.

Comment: Devices connected to system through USB includes:
`Keyboard` & 3 `microUsb cables` but the microusb cables are usually not connected to any devices at the time of startup.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: no as i said, the problem still persists even after trying above solutions.

Comment: Have you tried booting with your USBs unplugged, to see if it's caused by usb? Update UEFI from manufacturers site.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If you are not able to access the BIOS settings than your case should be similar to mine.

Try to disconnect the hard disk (or all hard drives attached) and start your PC.
If you are able to access the BIOS settings then your hard drive is damaged. Something wrong happened to your HDD (most probably electrical issue) and the mother board is stopping all kind of operations as protection to all devices.

I did not try to analyze the damage on my hard drive and if it can be fixed yet you can get a new hard drive and continue using your PC.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem recently with an Intel DQ67OW motherboard; in my case I was able to access the BIOS settings (<kbd>F2</kbd>) and boot manager (<kbd>F10</kbd>) before the lockup. It would happen even with all the hard drives disconnected. A few times removing and replacing the RAM seemed to fix the problem, but it would quickly reoccur. In the end I replaced the motherboard with another one of the same type, which corrected the problem. At first I thought that the 'bad' board had an intermittent physical fault such as a cracked trace or bad solder joint, but it did not display the same problem when mounted in a different case. I'm still inclined to suspect a physical fault, but one triggered by how that particular board was mounted in that particular case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the some issue some years back. Much to my surprise, changing the CMOS battery & resetting the BIOS resolved the symptoms.